# aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to write a query for a specific stack. It looks like this:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region $AWS_REGION --profile $AWS_PROFILE --stack-name MyStack --query 'Stacks[?StackName == "MyStack"]'
[]
```

As you can see the output is an empty array. On the other hand:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region $AWS_REGION --profile $AWS_PROFILE --stack-name MyStack --query 'Stacks[0]'
{
   // the output
}
```

What am I missing in my query version? How do I fix it?

Comment: @Paolo That's interesting. I just tried it in bash and get the same result (`[]`).

Comment: Actually, its `--query "Stacks[?StackName == 'MyStack']"` that works, and not `--query 'Stacks[?StackName == "MyStack"]'`

Comment: @Paolo Yup, switching the single and double quotes worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the value in backquotes:

```
--query 'Stacks[?StackName == `MyStack`]'
```

[Filtering AWS CLI output - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side-specific-values)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I figured it was something simple.

Comment: sorry to bother you with a follow up question...my full query is `--query 'Stacks[?StackName==`TrellisSPA`].Outputs[?OutputKey==`BucketName`].OutputValue`. Up to `.Outputs`, this seems to work, but even after following the same pattern, I can't seem to get the bucket name. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I needed an empty pair of brackets: `--query 'Stacks[?StackName==``TrellisSPA``][].Outputs[?OutputKey==``BucketName``].OutputValue`. Up to `.Outputs